# Inject PHP into Value attribute via Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, code-injection

I am trying to inject a value stored in a PHP $_SESSION variable into the "value" attribute of an input tag using javascript. I am able to successfully inject the PHP code in the "value" attribute, but the stored value does not appear in the text box. My code is below:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="" />
```

Javascript:

```
fields.eq(n).attr('value', "<?php echo $_SESSION['fname'] ; ?>");
```

The problem is that this would ***usually*** place the value of the `$_SESSION['fname']` variable in the input box. But that is *not* the case. When the button is clicked to inject the PHP code into the value attribute, this is what the HTML looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['fname'] ; ?>" />
```

And this is what I want it to look like but in the text box, it actually shows the PHP code and not the value stored in `$_SESSION['fname']`.

Is there something I am missing? Shouldn't this work? Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: i suspect its not php file since if its php file than it will show what stored in session fname

Comment: That's the thing, it is a PHP file. I thought exactly what you just said but it does not work. Any other ideas of why not? Thanks

Comment: there is no way ...that it will show what you said

Comment: Believe me, I have triple checked everything. One thing I know is that this is 100% a PHP file. I have hundreds of lines PHP code on this page so there is no mistaking it. I have never tried injecting the value like this before and I am guessing the web browser is not reading the HTML correctly.

Comment: Try to store the `$_SESSION['fname']` into a variable first, and then echo the variable.

Comment: You made that PHP variable into a string, remove the quotations.

Comment: @RogerNg its even not a good idea .... we should avoid singleton

Comment: @Ohgodwhy which quotation are you taking about ???`<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['fname'] ; ?>" />` is fine

Comment: @RogerNg I have `$_SESSION['fname']` is already created. So this is not the problem

Comment: @NullPointer I have updated the original posting with a picture so everyone can see what I am talking about.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Your solution did not work...thanks though

Comment: Did you use javascript to put the String `<?php echo $_SESSION['fname'] ; ?>` into that field value? Javascript executes after PHP, so it won't execute the PHP script.

Comment: @RogerNg Yes, this is what I did. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why don't you put that code in the PHP file? Another way is to pull the username from another PHP file using `AJAX GET`.

Comment: Are you placing the JavaScript inside a `<script>` element in the PHP file, or are you including the JavaScript via `<script src="blah.js"></script>`?

Comment: @AlvinWong I am including it. Does this make a difference?

Comment: tried ... possible it file is html ...but in php not possible

Comment: @three3 that's the problem. It is **not** a PHP file.

Comment: @RogerNg Does it make a difference if the file is included as so `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/inject.js"></script>`? Or does the javascript code have to be placed directly into the PHP script?

Comment: I think three3 has put the PHP script inside the javascript.

Comment: @RogerNg No, this is not correct. I have a PHP file that includes the javascript file.

Comment: @AlvinWong what do you mean it is not a PHP file?

Comment: For some reason, PHP is not being used by the web server to parse that file. Does it have the extension of `.php` or something else?

Comment: @TimPost The file extension is .php

Comment: Yes, the file extension is .php but you put PHP script inside the JavaScript. That's why it doesn't work. Please check my answer to see if it works for you.

Comment: And yet other code 'just works' in the same file? E.g. you're _certain_ that PHP is in fact being called to parse it?

Comment: @RogerNg You are correct, I was using PHP inside a javascript `fields.eq(n).attr('value', "<?php echo $_SESSION['fname'] ; ?>");` Although I was including the javascript file in my PHP script, was not working. I am going to try your solution now.

Comment: @RogerNg What he's doing should work, the variable should be expanded and inserted in the JS as a string. e.g. `var num_items = <?php echo $num_items;?>;` would initialize the `num_items` JS var.

Comment: @TimPost I strongly doubt if his JavaScript is called through PHP as `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/inject.js"></script>` is used to call the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server-side script, which means: PHP will be executed on the server.

JavaScript is a client script, which means: JavaScript will be executed by the browser.

Usually by default, `.php` files will be processed by the PHP engine **on the server**, thus executing the PHP scripts. The result will be sent to the client. That's why when you have a `.php` file, things between `<?php` and `?>` will be processed by the PHP engine and you will not *see* the actual PHP script in the client. Sometimes you can configure the HTTP server such that `.html` files are also processed by the PHP engine.

For other files, the HTTP server (e.g. Apache) will directly sent the whole file to the client, without being processed by the PHP engine, so that any PHP scripts will *not* be processed and will directly go to the client.

Now your problem is that you tried to put some PHP into a JavaScript file (`.js`), and hoping that it will be executed, but in fact it will *not*. So when you try to set the value of your input element with your shown JavaScript, the "text" `<?php echo $_SESSION['fname'] ; ?>` will be set.

If you either put the JavaScript *into* your `.php` file, or rename your JavaScript file (`*.js`) to `*.php`, you will get the value you desired.

Or probably you could add an extra JavaScript in your page, setting a "global" variable with your PHP, and use that "global variable" in your `.js` file.
i.e. `window.myFname = <?php echo $_SESSION['fname'] ; ?>;`

---

Depending on what you want to do, you may need to choose how to design. If you just simply want to set the value, you may just simply do one of the two suggestions I've provided. If you want to get the value *dynamically* (i.e. obtain the value when you need it), you would like AJAX like others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Php code is interpreted at request time so you will have to thing about the code you "inject" as a simple string as far as the browser/javascript is concerned.

You can do it like this, with a callback that returns the calue of the session var:

```
$('#someButton').click(function() {
     $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: <callbackUrl>,
           data: <params if any>
           }).done(function( msg ) {
                fields.eq(n).attr('value', msg);
                });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have included the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library.

**getUser.php**

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['fname']; ?>
```

For your **JavaScript**,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("getUser.php", function(data) {
      fields.eq(n).attr('value', data);
    });
});
```

For reference, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: I am going to try this out now. Will let you know if it works. Thanks